# Calculating the population inside and outside a buffer

Tags: statistics, buffer, arcgis

I have to calculate the population inside 1000m cells. The total population inside the cell in the images below is 2306.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF5sz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzTli.png)

The green is the buffer from a point. The orange falls outside the buffer. The population distribution inside the cell is even and I have to calculate the population for the buffered area and the area outside of it in the cell.

I clipped the buffered layer and made another layer with just the unbuffered area. But I am not sure how to get the population for these.

Area of the cell/1000 * population of the cell

Population of the cell/160000 * area

I calculated the fields using different formulas other than the above mentioned ones but the calculated fields were not right (I am bad at math) because when I summarised the fields, the total went way too high, even above the overall population of the all the cells combined which is around 160000.

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right. However, you said last time you calculated the fields, you used a different formula. Have you tried again with the formula above?

Comment: @PintSizeSlash3r I actually figured it out by calculating the population by population/area before performing an intersect and erase. I will multiply the result population with the buffered and unbuffered area. Hopefully, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find pop density.
I would certaily calculate area in square meters, but is not mandatory if all areas are in the same unit all will goes well.

1. Big square pop density = 2306 [pop] / Big square Area [area unit]
2. just multiply the polygons areas by this number.

Do this for both polygons.
pol area [area unit] * Big square pop density [pop/area unit]

ie:
[image]